# How to get subfigure alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have a 3 figures and I am trying to put them on one line but I can't achieve that.
Any help would be great. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% Packages
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdftricks}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,calc,arrows,shapes,snakes,automata,backgrounds,petri,positioning,fit}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=5mm,>=stealth',bend angle=20,auto,
  place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=8mm},
  red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
  every label/.style={red},
  every node/.style={scale=0.8},
  dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt},
  initial text={},
  scale=.8]
  \node [place,accepting] (l0)  {$l_1$};
  \node [place,below=8mm of l0] (l1) [label=right:$x\le 10$] {$l_2$};
  \node [place,below=1.3cm of l1] (l2) {$l_3$};

  \path (l0) edge node [align=center, xshift =0.7cm]{init \\ reset\{x,y\}} (l1)
    (l1) edge [bend left] node [align=center]{$cont$ \\ $y \ge 20$ \\ reset\{x,y\}} (l2)
         edge [loop,in=120,out=150,looseness=10] node [align=center,below,xshift=-8mm,yshift=5mm]{$loop$ \\ $x=10$ \\ reset\{x\}} (l1)
    (l2) edge [bend left] node[align=center] {$end$ \\ reset\{x,y\}} (l1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\centering An atomic BIP component}
  \label{fig:z1}
  \end{subfigure}
  %\node [inner ysep=3.7cm,inner xsep=2.5cm, draw, right=1.2cm of l0, above=-1.2cm of l2] (rec1) {};
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=7mm,>=stealth',bend angle=20,auto,
  place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10mm},
  red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
  every label/.style={red},
  every node/.style={scale=.7},
  dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt},
  initial text={}]
  \node [right=5cm of l0](s0){$\ll l_1, x=y\gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s0](s1){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge x=y  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s1,xshift=-2cm](s2){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 10  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s2,xshift=0cm](s3){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 20  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s3,xshift=0cm](s4){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 30  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s4,xshift=0cm](s5){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s5,xshift=0cm](s6){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y > 20 \wedge y-x > 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s6,xshift=3cm](s7){$\ll l_3,  y=x  \gg$};
  \node [right=0cm of s6](s8){};

  \path (s0) edge (s1)
    (s1) edge (s2)
    (s2) edge (s3)
    (s3) edge (s4)
    (s4) edge (s5)
    (s5) edge (s6)
    (s6) edge (s7)
    (s8) edge[looseness=10,loop,right,out=-20,in=20](s8)
    (s7)++(1,0) edge[bend right] ++(-5mm,4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\centering Symbolic states representation before normalization}
  \label{fig:z2}
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,node distance=7mm,>=stealth',bend angle=20,auto,
  place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10mm},
  red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
  every label/.style={red},
  every node/.style={scale=.7},
  dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt},
  initial text={}]
  \node [right=5cm of s0](t0){$\ll l_1, x=y\gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t0](t1){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge x=y  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t1,xshift=-2cm](t2){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 10  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t2,xshift=0cm](t3){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 20  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t3,xshift=0cm](t4){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 30  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t4,xshift=0cm](t5){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t5,xshift=0cm](t6){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y > 20 \wedge y-x > 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t6,xshift=3cm](t7){$\ll l_3,  y=x  \gg$};
  \node [right=0cm of t6](t8){};

  \path (t0) edge (t1)
    (t1) edge (t2)
    (t2) edge (t3)
    (t3) edge (t4)
    (t4) edge (t5)
    (t5) edge (t6)
    (t6) edge (t7)
    (t8) edge[looseness=10,loop,right,out=-20,in=20](t8)
    (t7)++(1,0) edge[bend right] ++(-5mm,4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{\centering Symbolic states representation after normalization}
  \label{fig:z3}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{An atomic component and its symbolic state representations}\label{fig:zone}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the blank line between the second and third subfigure.

Comment: since 3 times `.3\textwidth` is less than the full width, you can put `\hfil` between the subfigures.  the blank line (as pointed out by mico) puts you into vertical mode (it's equivalent to `\par`), and to keep these in the same line, you need to stay in horizontal mode.

Comment: Your example is far away from being minimal. Can you please cancel out all that packages that are irrelevant to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious your picture is to wide to be fit in text width. See comparison:
[image]

As you can see, figures b and c overlap. What to do:
1. enlarge (locally text width for example with help of package `changepage`. With

```
\adjustwidth}{<leftmargin>}{<rightmargin>}
 <your figures>
\end{adjustwidth}
```

2. redesign your second and third figures so, that their width will not exceed `0.32\textwidth`. In this case you can obtain:

[image]

Above figures I generate with following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                fit,
                petri,positioning,plotmarks,
                shapes,snakes}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Symbolic states representation before normalization}
        \label{fig:z1}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Symbolic states representation before normalization}
    \label{fig:z2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Symbolic states representation after normalization}
    \label{fig:z3}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{An atomic component and its symbolic state representations}
\label{fig:zone}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-12mm}{-12mm}    
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.27\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=5mm,
>=stealth',
bend angle=20,auto,
place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=8mm},
red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
every label/.style={red},
every node/.style={scale=0.8},
dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt},
initial text={},
scale=.8]
  \node [place,accepting] (l0)  {$l_1$};
  \node [place,below=8mm of l0] (l1) [label=right:$x\le 10$] {$l_2$};
  \node [place,below=1.3cm of l1] (l2) {$l_3$};
%
  \path (l0) edge node [align=center,xshift =0.7cm]{init\\ reset\{x,y\}} (l1)
    (l1) edge [bend left] node [align=center]{$cont$ \\$y\ge20$\\ reset\{x,y\}} (l2)
         edge [loop,in=120,out=150,looseness=10] node [align=center,below,xshift=-8mm,yshift=5mm]{$loop$\\$x=10$\\ reset\{x\}} (l1)
    (l2) edge [bend left] node[align=center] {$end$ \\ reset\{x,y\}} (l1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Symbolic states representation before normalization}
        \label{fig:z1}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=7mm,
>=stealth',
bend angle=20,auto,
place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10mm},
red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
every label/.style={red},
every node/.style={scale=.7},
dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt},
initial text={}]
%xscale=.8]
  \node [right=5cm of l0](s0){$\ll l_1, x=y\gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s0](s1){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge x=y  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s1,xshift=-2cm](s2){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 10  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s2,xshift=0cm](s3){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 20  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s3,xshift=0cm](s4){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 30  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s4,xshift=0cm](s5){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s5,xshift=0cm](s6){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y > 20 \wedge y-x > 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of s6,xshift=3cm](s7){$\ll l_3,  y=x  \gg$};
  \node [right=0cm of s6](s8){};

  \path (s0) edge (s1)
    (s1) edge (s2)
    (s2) edge (s3)
    (s3) edge (s4)
    (s4) edge (s5)
    (s5) edge (s6)
    (s6) edge (s7)
    (s8) edge[looseness=10,loop,right,out=-20,in=20](s8)
    (s7)++(1,0) edge[bend right] ++(-5mm,4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{Symbolic states representation before normalization}
    \label{fig:z2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=7mm,
>=stealth',
bend angle=20,auto,
place/.style={circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=10mm},
red place/.style={place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20}
every label/.style={red},
every node/.style={scale=.7},
dots/.style={fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt},
initial text={}]
%xscale=.8]
  \node [right=5cm of s0](t0){$\ll l_1, x=y\gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t0](t1){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge x=y  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t1,xshift=-2cm](t2){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 10  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t2,xshift=0cm](t3){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 20  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t3,xshift=0cm](t4){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 30  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t4,xshift=0cm](t5){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y \le 20 \wedge y-x = 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t5,xshift=0cm](t6){$\ll l_2, x \le 10 \wedge y > 20 \wedge y-x > 40  \gg$};
  \node [below=3mm of t6,xshift=3cm](t7){$\ll l_3,  y=x  \gg$};
  \node [right=0cm of t6](t8){};

  \path (t0) edge (t1)
    (t1) edge (t2)
    (t2) edge (t3)
    (t3) edge (t4)
    (t4) edge (t5)
    (t5) edge (t6)
    (t6) edge (t7)
    (t8) edge[looseness=10,loop,right,out=-20,in=20](t8)
    (t7)++(1,0) edge[bend right] ++(-5mm,4cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Symbolic states representation after normalization}
    \label{fig:z3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \caption{An atomic component and its symbolic state representations}
\label{fig:zone}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```